# How to include a small sample application in a class library project?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I have written a class library which contains WPF controls. I thought it would be a good idea to document the features in the form of a small app which includs the controls.

I am having difficult configuring the project.

-- Should I make it a Windows application? But then I'll need to sign it.

-- If I make it a class library then I can't set a startup object.

-- Do I make 2 projects? One for the library, one for the demo app.

What is the 'approved' way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *need* a Windows application to demonstrate the controls in actual use. There's no way around that at all; a class library can not execute on its own. so make one for the library, as you already have, and one for a demo app.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution (and I belive the most right one) on my opinion is to make separate Windows application. It will demonstrate usage of your controls and will not overload the library